# Why does this query return results?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT
IFNULL(IF(IFNULL(tab2.tab_qty, 0) <= 0,
    tab1.tab_qty,
    SUM(tab1.tab_qty + IFNULL(tab2.tab_qty, 0))
) ,0) AS tab_qty
FROM my_table tab1
JOIN my_table tab2 ON (tab1.table_id = tab2.tab_table_id)
WHERE tab1.table_id = ?
```

If `tab1.table_id` is `1` and no record exists where `tab2.tab_table_id = 1` why does the query return results equal to the value of `tab1.tab_qty`?

My line of thinking is the `JOIN` fails so `tab2.tab_qty` is `null` causing the `IF` to enter the true branch. This should return the value of `tab1.tab_qty` to be returned, but since the `JOIN` failed and it is not a `LEFT JOIN` then the value of `tab1.tab_qty` is also `NULL` and should return `0` as the final result.

Using MariaDB. ID Fields are INTEGER type and QTY fields are DECIMAL type.

Comment: It does return 0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=295f94b6c79a411c753e6523a2b5f5c2

Comment: When you introduce the aggregate you're gonna to get one row in the result. The sum itself evaluates to null.

Comment: @shawnt00 But that side of the IF isn't being evaluated.

Comment: @Nick using that identical query with only tables and columns renamed I am getting a different result on my server. Version 10.3.22 of MariaDB. So confused.

Comment: Unfortunately if we can't reproduce the error it's difficult to offer advice to fix it.

Comment: Why does removing the SUM have an effect on this though of that branch is never evaluated?

Comment: Note that as @shawnt00 pointed out, it's only because of the `SUM` in your formula that you get a result at all; the fact that it *might* not be evaluated in the end doesn't matter.

Comment: without data supplied by you we are largely guessing. I would agree with your summation and that you should get zero. If tab1.tab_qty is returned than I suggest the data isn't what you think it is, or the query is different.

Comment: Your query should return an error, because you have no `group by` and the query is mixing aggregated an non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of an aggregation function forces a row to be returned, even if there is no match found for the inner join. Consider the following

```
create table my_table (table_id int, tab_qty decimal, tab_table_id int)
insert into my_table (table_id, tab_qty, tab_table_id) values
(1, 10, 2),
(2, 5, 2)

select
    tab1.table_id as no_join_is_no_row
FROM my_table tab1
INNER JOIN my_table tab2 ON tab1.table_id = tab2.tab_table_id
WHERE tab1.table_id = 1
```

**No Row Returned**

```
+-------------------+
| no_join_is_no_row |
+-------------------+
```

But if we now request `sum(tab1.tab_qty)` in that same simple query where the still is no matching rows in the table:

```
select
    sum(tab1.tab_qty) forced_row_by_aggregation
FROM my_table tab1
INNER JOIN my_table tab2 ON tab1.table_id = tab2.tab_table_id
WHERE tab1.table_id = 1
```

**Result does have 1 row**

```
+---------------------------+
| forced_row_by_aggregation |
+---------------------------+
| null                      |
+---------------------------+
```

So in your original query `IF(IFNULL(tab2.tab_qty, 0) <= 0`  tab2.tab_qty IS NULL, so 0 is returned, and the IF is now true (as 0 is <= 0) so the next parameter is used `tab1.tab_qty` and that is also NULL, so now the outermost `IFNULL(....,0)` kicks in and returns zero.

You can trace this by altering the query to return something other than zeros by the various IFNULLs, e.g.

```
SELECT 
 IFNULL(IF(IFNULL(tab2.tab_qty, -1) <= 0,          -- minus 1
     tab1.tab_qty,
     SUM(tab1.tab_qty + IFNULL(tab2.tab_qty, -2))  -- minus 2
 ) ,-3) AS tab_qty                                 -- minus 3
FROM my_table tab1
INNER JOIN my_table tab2 ON (tab1.table_id = tab2.tab_table_id)
WHERE tab1.table_id = 1
```

**Which Returns**

```
+---------+
| tab_qty |
+---------+
|      -3 |
+---------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=47d7977c3c4b2ee19dccaf5528d0f4e7)*
(*apologies to nick for re-use of example*)

nb: You can alter the dbms version at that fiddle

Comment: No apology required, I'm glad it was useful. Not sure I agree with your last section; the `-1` and `-2` are intermediate results which would never appear on the output. Might also be worth noting that even in the presence of a test which means the aggregation function cannot be executed, it still is e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=58b84315289e47314299843010229848

Comment: @Nick -1 -2 -3 was only intended to clearly differentiate, even if never seen. I thought I had made the point that the row appears even though a very similar query returns no row , was that not clear. mmmm

Comment: I just thought it was confusing to use the `-1` and `-2` values because they will never appear on the output, regardless of what the inputs are. But maybe that's just the way my brain works... my other point was that in the fiddle I linked to there is no way the `SUM` will ever be calculated, but its mere presence in the query causes aggregation to occur whether the result set has 0 or any number of rows.